# Is it possible to update android app from private server while running?

Tags: android

I have to develop some specific software, which sometimes can't connect to the App store, but I will have to send some updates. this software can be restarted but it needs to check for updates itself and download it, so I am looking for ways to update like Facebook is doing for example. Change its own package and restart, but I could not find any helpful information or SDK to do so. What is the right way to do so? How can I achieve that.

edit: I have seen some solutions. One is having 2 apps (1 updater and 1 main app, it is ok but I am looking for a bit more flexible ways if possible). And SDK-s just send you to the download page, but I need my app to download and install it itself (This software will be used as a middlware controlling app for IPTV devices, so there is no security issues in terms of not notifying user about update, I'll handle it with popups)

Comment: You can use live db like firebase or any other service or you can use API there are many solutions its depend upon you what's you want to use.

Comment: The thing is I have to update not only a database but I will have to deliver some bug fixes and improvements

Comment: Can you explain me please if you talk about facebook they are using JSON and set live data in these objects so no need of update in live db. ... If you want to improve your app code or improve some features so you needs update

Comment: I did not know that it was live data. I can give you another example. In-game updaters such as Hearthstone.
https://i.imgur.com/pameE63.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an API in android for update apps. It is called In-app Updates.
Basically, it has two options:

- Flexible: The user choose if he wants to update the app or not

> A user experience that provides background download and installation with graceful state monitoring. This UX is appropriate when it’s acceptable for the user to use the app while downloading the update. For example, you want to urge users to try a new feature that’s not critical to the core functionality of your app.

- Immediate: The app shows a screen where the user must be update the app

> A full screen user experience that requires the user to update and restart the app in order to continue using the app. This UX is best for cases where an update is critical for continued use of the app. After a user accepts an immediate update, Google Play handles the update installation and app restart.

In your case, you can use the "Inmediate" option

References:

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

Comment: Well, I have seen this answer too, can I publish my app on appstore visible only for users already having it only for updates ?

edit: I did additional search and there is sthing such as private apps on Play store. This might work I think if the device can support Play store Services. Thank you.